# Where can i find Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas file post installation of RAD Studio 10.4?

Tags: rad-studio, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am looking for few Delphi controls(TControl) and their structures of Delphi version 10.4.Thought of installing RAD Studio 10.4 trial and searching for file(s) such as Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas. I am unable to find those file(s),though I can see only binary files of it.

1. Can anybody guide me out on getting this file?
2. Is it a limitation of Trial version of RAD Studio?

Comment: Source code is not included in the trial versions. You only get the binary .dcu files.

Answer (score 0):

The source files are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source` for a standard installation.

No idea if source code is delivered or not with trial version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fpiette.

I could see the files in the above mentioned location only on community edition not on trial version, that is a limitation